# Calculated column to retrieve number from external data column

Tags: sharepoint-2010, calculated-columns

I have a external data column that brings number and text.

External data: 10000 text
I need to retrieve only the number of that external data column to calculated column. And the number is always 5 digits.

I have tried LEFT, FIND, TRIM... but nothing seems to be good enough to SharePoint 2010 to accept.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what your trying to achieve, but this formula works fine within my Calculated Column:

```
=LEFT([External Data],5)
```